# Dynamically allocating memory for a string of arbitrary length

Tags: c, string, function, dynamic, allocation

I want to create a function that counts the number of occurances of character c in string str no matter  whether in the string character c is uppercase of lowercase. I am trying to use  toupper and tolower functions but it is not working.

In the main function I want to dynamically allocate memory for a character array of at most 50 characters, using the malloc function, and then read the input string using fgets. Then I want to correctly allocate memory for the input string by using the malloc function but according to the length of the input string. Then I want to copy the input string into the other string of the right size, and free the memory allocated at the beginning. I don't know why but the malloc function is not allocating 50 characters at the beginning. When I print the length of the input string, it doesn't count past 7 characters. What am I missing?

This is what my code looks like:

```
int count_insensitive(char *str, char c){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\n'; i++){
        if(( str[i] == toupper(c)) || str[i] == tolower(c) ){
            count++;
        }     
    }
    return count;
}

int main(){
    char *a_str;
    a_str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
    fgets(a_str, sizeof(a_str), stdin);
    printf("%lu\n", strlen(a_str));
    char *a_str2;
    a_str2 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(a_str)));
    strcpy(a_str2, a_str); 
    printf("%s\n", a_str2);
    free(a_str);

    printf("The character 'b' occurs %d times\n", count_insensitive(a_str2, 'b'));
    printf("The character 'H' occurs %d times\n", count_insensitive(a_str2, 'H'));
    printf("The character '8' occurs %d times\n", count_insensitive(a_str2, '8'));
    printf("The character 'u' occurs %d times\n", count_insensitive(a_str2, 'u'));
    printf("The character '$' occurs %d times\n", count_insensitive(a_str2, '$'));
```

If I input this string:

```
Hello world hello world
```

The output is this:

```
7
hello w
The character 'b' occurs 15 times
The character 'H' occurs 47 times
The character '8' occurs 18 times
The character 'u' occurs 17 times
The character '$' occurs 6 times
```

Comment: Hannah McDermott, Curious, why code with `"%lu"` in `printf("%lu\n", strlen(a_str));` instead of `"%zu"`?

Answer (score -1):

By performing chux comment and some little change this is working version of code. 
I will write some explanation in following hours.

***Code***

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int count_insensitive(char *str, char c){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\n'; i++){
        if(( str[i] == toupper(c)) || str[i] == tolower(c) ){
            count++;
        }     
    }
    return count;
}


int main()
{

    char *a_str;
    a_str = malloc(50);
    fgets(a_str, 50, stdin);
    printf("%zu\n", strlen(a_str));
    char *a_str2;
    a_str2 = malloc(strlen(a_str));
    strcpy(a_str2, a_str); 
    printf("%s\n", a_str2);
    free(a_str);

    printf("The character 'b' occurs %d times\n", count_insensitive(a_str2, 'b'));
    printf("The character 'H' occurs %d times\n", count_insensitive(a_str2, 'H'));
    printf("The character '8' occurs %d times\n", count_insensitive(a_str2, '8'));
    printf("The character 'u' occurs %d times\n", count_insensitive(a_str2, 'u'));
    printf("The character '$' occurs %d times\n", count_insensitive(a_str2, '$'));

}
```

Comment: Memory leak of `a_str2`. No allowance for 0 terminators. Assumption about line endings. Why compare to `toupper()` and `tolower()` ? Why not just `toupper()` the starting character and then you just need to compare to `toupper()` in the string. Copletely ignores the source of the bug in the original. Just providing working code with no explanation is not a good answer!